# Eisenbud exercise 21.9 and the uniqueness of Frobenius structure on Gorenstein rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am learning some basic things about Gorenstein rings. Here is exercise 21.9 in Eisenbud's book *Commutative Algebra With A View Towards Algebraic Geometry* attached:

> Let $A,P$ be a zero-dimensional local ring, finite-dimensional as a vector space over a field $k\cong A/P$. Suppose that $A$ is Gorenstein. Let $\varphi : A \rightarrow k$ be a linear functional on $A$.
>   Show that the symmetric bilinear form $\langle a, b \rangle = \varphi(ab)$ is nonsingular iff $\varphi(ab)$ is nonzero on the socle of $A$.
>   Show that this form is an invariant of $A$ (as a $k$-algebra); 
>   for example, if $k = \mathbb{R}$ then the signature of this form is an invariant of $A$. (When $F = (f_1,..., f_r) : R^r\to R^r$ is an analytic mapping taking 0 to 0, and $f_1,..., f_r$ is a regular sequence in the ring of real analytic germs of functions at 0, then this signature is the local degree at the origin of $F$; that is, the number of times $F$ wraps a small sphere about the origin in the source space around a small sphere about the origin in the target space. See Eisenbud and Levine [1977].)

I have proved $\langle a, b \rangle = \varphi(ab)$ is nonsingular iff $\varphi(ab)$ is nonzero on the socle of $A$.

My questions are:

1. In which sense is $\langle a, b \rangle=φ(ab)$ an invariant of $A$? I know that it is a quadratic form on $A$ so it depends on the basis we choose.
2. Let $A$ be a Gorenstein local ring of finite dimension. Is Frobenius structure unique on $A$ up to algebra automorphism? In other words, what is the orbit of non-degenerate maps $\varphi: A \rightarrow k$ under the action of Aut($A$)? (I have checked all local algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ of $\dim A\leq 6$ and the answer is yes.)